# C# Select one ip per thread from list

Tags: c#

My program is a multi threaded proxy checker and whenever I return the proxy ip addresses from my method and try to echo them out I'm getting a bunch and the threads are doing it completely unintended. It's supposed to supply each thread with a line of IP addresses. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/6cc6fecc8b5bbd0428f568492656669f.png) of what's echoing.

My plagued code (bear with me, based off a public example):

```
static List<String> ips = new List<String>();// this is at the start of the program class

static Random rnd = new Random();

private static String getip()
{
    if (ips.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return ips[rnd.Next(0, ips.Count)];
}
```

Also the get IP is called in a `while (true)` loop as it's a proxy checker

The other code:

```
while (true)
{
    string ip = getip();
    try
    {
        using (var client = new ProxyClient(ip, user, pass))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ip, user, pass);
            client.Connect();
            if (client.IsConnected)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                client.Disconnect();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        removeip(ip);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(30);
}
```

For example, thread 1 should have 127.0.0.1 (first IP from list), thread 2, 127.0.0.2 (second IP from list) etc etc, the problem at the moment is located in the screenshot.

My threading code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Worker), i);
}
```

Comment: One ip per thread.

Comment: @EricJ - look at this if you can

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that all threads are running and might select the same IP. Using something as Random is a bad practice here. You'd better use `Parallel.ForEach()` it will handle all items multithreaded and doesn't select the same IP twice. The `Parallel.ForEach()` will block until all items are handled *(on the `ThreadPool`)*

You could try this:

```
public class MyIP
{
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public bool AcceptsConnection { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
var l = new List<MyIP>();

// create a copy of `l`, so i can delete items
Parallel.ForEach(l.ToArray(), (item) =>
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new ProxyClient(item.IP, user, pass))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.IP, user, pass);
            client.Connect();
            item.AcceptsConnection = client.IsConnected;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        l.Remove(item);
    }
});

foreach(var item in l)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.IP + " is " + (item.AcceptsConnection) ? " accepts connections" : " doesn not accept connections");
}
```

You may alter the `AcceptsConnection` property, because there is only one thread accessing it. *(unless you're doing something extra in the background)*

Comment: Now on the method that contains all of this code ( private static Boolean CheckProxy(String user, String pass)) is throwing an error .CheckProxy(string, string)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Also I'm using an component (dll or whatever) for this and i need to know when the client is connected so i can return true/false for my other code to work. @JeroenvanLangen

Comment: If you are surrounding the `ProxyClient` with a using, your connection will be dropped when leaving this scope.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I've done this because there might be times where the user/pass is wrong. and i'd like to know that.

Comment: Thats because when you have an exception, there isn't a return value. So add return false in the catch

Comment: Error 2 Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Action<Program.MyIP,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,long>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: Error 1 Since 'System.Action<Program.MyIP,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,long>' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: on return false mate

Comment: I didn't used a method in my parallel example... Also, i didn't use a *return* value...

Comment: @Jeroenvarlangen "Thats because when you have an exception, there isn't a return value. So add return false in the catch"?